# Where can I connect with german magento users?

Tags: magento-community

i am using the communitiy edition of magento but missing the community!!!
there are so many translation problems in the german magento backend so it wont help to ask english users.

thougt magento is such an individual customized shop (therefore i bought it) but ive got many problems and no one (german) to ask

Answer (score 1):

The community often meets on round tables, a list of the round tables can be found here: http://www.magento-stammtisch.de/

The translation shipped with magento 1.9 is awful, a better, community driven translation can be found here:

https://github.com/riconeitzel/German_LocalePack_de_DE
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/locale-mage-community-de-de.html

Where are you from? You can find many informations about the german community on http://firegento.com/.

If you have more questions, just send me an email.